# Mean average precision (mAP) in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, average-precision

I need to calculate the **mAP** described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37498432/7649980) for **object detection** using **Tensorflow**.

**Average precision(AP)** is a typical performance measure used for ranked  sets. AveragePrecision is defined as the average of the precision scores after each   true  positive, TP in the scope  S. Given  a scope  S =  7,and  a  ranked list (gain vector)  G  = [1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,..]
where  1/0  indicate the gains associated to relevant/non-­‐relevant items,  respectively:

AP = (1/1 + 2/2 + 3/4 + 4/5) / 4    = 0.8875.

**Mean Average Precision (mAP)**: average of the average precision value for a  set of queries.

i got 5 **One-Hot** tensors with the predictions:

```
prediction_A 
prediction_B
prediction_C 
prediction_D 
prediction_E
```

where a single prediction tensor has this structure (for example prediction_A):

```
00100
01000
00001
00010
00010
```

Then i've got the correct labels (one-hot) tensors, with the same structure:

```
y_A
y_B
y_C
y_D
y_E
```

i want compute **mAP** using **tensorflow**, cause i want summarize that, how i can do it?

i found this [function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/metrics/streaming_sparse_average_precision_at_k)  but i can't use it, cause i have a multidimensional vector.

I also write a python function that compute **AP** but it doesn't use Tensorflow

```
def compute_av_precision(match_list):
    n = len(match_list)
    tp_counter = 0

    cumulate_precision = 0
    for i in range(0,n):
        if match_list[i] == True:

            tp_counter += 1

            cumulate_precision += (float(tp_counter)/float(i+1))


    if tp_counter != 0:
        av_precision = cumulate_precision/float(tp_counter)
        return av_precision
    return 0
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you may need this one:

```
tf.metrics.average_precision_at_k
```

this method takes labels and prediction to calcualte the AP@K you mentioned

below are the referenced links

> https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/average_precision_at_k
>
> which implemented AP@K metric defined here:
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_measures_(information_retrieval)#Average_precision
>
> BTW, if you need a metric in Tensorflow, firstly you should search inside their official documents. Here is a list of all implemented metrics
>
> https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics

cheers

Comment: I do not think this is a complete answer, mAP is different from what you mention, because we need to keep the IOU in mind.